# How do I create inline comments in a Google Doc using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I have created an add on for google docs using app script but I am running into two issues. I am using the drive api to create comments in the document. However, I have 2 problems:

1. We cannot embed comments to a particular line inside the google document, so we can't create inline comments.
2. When creating a comment, the comment only appears once you refresh the document.

Is this something we are not doing correctly?

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690869/copy-google-sheet-with-app-script-retaining-comments

Comment: AFAIK, this is not yet available. There is a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37692298/5995040) that explain why this feature is not available using the API and gave a series of reported feature requests for this. You can also star it to help the engineers notice the request.