# How to completely copy a file in google drive via Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

How to perform a full copy of a file including all comments in Google Drive using Apps Script? The file to be copied can be a document, presentation, spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to copy a file using Apps Script using the [makeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopy)
function.
[image]

Here's a sample function you can use:

```
function copyToFolder(){
  var destinationFolderId = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID of destination folder")
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("ID of file to Copy")
  file.makeCopy("New File Name" + file,destinationFolderId);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's easy. But the comments are not copied

Comment: @AleksandrPomozov You'll have to insert the comments and replies to the file using Drive API. Please see this similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877531/script-for-a-google-doc-makecopy-the-comments-arent-copied